# SVG picture is returning with black background in flutter despite setting an transparent background SVG image file. help needed

Tags: flutter, web, svg, mobile, flutter-dependencies

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<rect width="200" height="200" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0_3_3" transform="scale(0.00555556)"/>
</pattern>
<image id="image0_3_3" width="180" height="180" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
</defs>
</svg>
```

SVG picture is returning with black background in flutter despite setting an transparent background SVG image file.

Changed the SVG file multiple times, and the result is the same.

I tried changes in the SVG file. But it seems like it's a problem in the flutter end.

Comment: Please share your SVG file

Comment: @MalayPatel Please check the question description. I have updated with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your SVG code has "image" tag which won't render in Flutter. You will have to convert the SVG to PNG and use it in your application. You can use [this converter](https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-png) to convert it if you want.

Using SVG makes no sense when SVG itself is loading images. Using PNG would be better.

Comment: Is there any way to edit the "image" tag for the svg to load? we cant use PNG.